# Keyboard overlaps Text View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have tried some solutions that are out there, but they do not work they way I need them to.

I have quite a long text field that will have several paragraphs inside of it. When a user taps on the text field, their keyboard pops up and basically blocks about half the text that's already there and the keyboard prevents them from making any additions to the text field, since the user cannot see what they are typing.

I have tried modifying the frame definition to go above the keyboard, but since the textfield is so long, the user can still go below the keyboard if they add enough text. Wrapping the text view inside a scroll view doesn't do much either.

I am using swift + xcode 6

Here is a screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image]

Comment: You can use a `NSLayoutConstraint` to resize the UITextView's frame.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you're using the autolayout, you can do the following :

In the .h, define a `NSLayouConstraint` :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *keyboardHeight;
```

In the .m :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue *kbFrame = [info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardFrame = [kbFrame CGRectValue];

    self.keyboardHeight.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    self.keyboardHeight.constant = 20;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Then link `keyboardHeight` with the vertical autolayout constraint between the `UITextView` and the bottom of the view :

[image]

Comment: This is the same approach I would have recommended.

Comment: I mentioned that I was using Swift + xcode 6 in the question, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to adjust the size of your text view as is appropriate. You can get the dimensions of the keyboard via the `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey` of the user dictionary.

E.g. a Swift version of [Apple's code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7):

```
func keyboardWasShown(aNotifcation: NSNotification) {

    let info = aNotifcation.userInfo as NSDictionary?
    let rectValue = info![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as NSValue
    let kbSize = rectValue.CGRectValue().size

    let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, kbSize.height, 0)
    textView.contentInset = contentInsets
    textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    // optionally scroll
    let aRect = textView.superview!.frame
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height
    let targetRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10) // get a relevant rect in the text view
    if !aRect.contains(targetRect.origin) {
        textView.scrollRectToVisible(targetRect, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mundi is right. This is an example of how to implement it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25267966/storyboard-scroll-view-with-text-boxes/25268455#25268455